# How to order a column by group in R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame (say "df") looks like following:

```
Hospital.Name | State | Mortality.Rate
'hospital_1'   | 'AA'  | 0.2
'hospital_2'   | 'AA'   | 0.3
'hospital_3'   | 'BB'  | 0.3
'hospital_4'   | 'CC'  | 0.5
```

(The Hospital.Name is unique)

Now I want to order the "Mortality.Rate" group by "State", i.e. order the rate within a certain state. If there is a tie in the rate, then "Hospital.Name" is used for resolve the tie.

The "order()" and "tapply()" functions came to my mind. I coded like this:

```
tapply(df$Mortality.Rate, df$State, order, df$Hospital.Name, na.last=NA)
```

However, an error "argument length differ" popped up. When "order" function is applied to a sliced "Rate", the second argument of order (i.e. df$Hospital.Name) is not sliced.

How could I pass the second argument (for resolution a tie in ordering) to tapply() or is there any other approaches?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In base R, you can supply multiple arguments to `order()` and subsequent arguments are used to break ties in the earlier variables, as in:

```
df[order(df$State,df$Mortality.Rate,df$Hospital.Name),]
```

Comment: No need for the quotes around the `Mortality.Rate`.

Comment: Where's the `Hospital.Name` part?

Comment: @Jthorpe True, but it’s a form of [cargo cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I was just being lazy (not removing the quotes I copy/pasted from the OP), not trying to solve a problem with quotes...

Comment: It took me a while to understand. It is a nice and clean resolution. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

you can do it in `dplyr`:

```
df %>% group_by(State) %>% arrange(Mortality.Rate, Hospital.Name)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I need to stick to base R when finding the resolution (sorry about not mentioning it in my question). I will have a look at this package. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in dplyr. First, some sample data:

```
library("dplyr")
hospital_name <- sample(c("hospital_1", "hospital_2", "hospital_3"), 10,
                        replace = TRUE)
state <- sample(letters[1:3], 10, replace = TRUE)
mortality_rate <- runif(10)

df <- data_frame(hospital_name, state, mortality_rate)
```

Group by state, then arrange by columns.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(state) %>% 
  arrange(mortality_rate, hospital_name)
```

Producing results like these, where the states are grouped and the mortality rate is sorted within each state.

```
## Source: local data frame [10 x 3]
## Groups: state
## 
##    hospital_name state mortality_rate
## 1     hospital_1     b     0.15293591
## 2     hospital_1     b     0.37417167
## 3     hospital_1     b     0.54561856
## 4     hospital_3     c     0.02487033
## 5     hospital_1     c     0.09937557
## 6     hospital_1     c     0.35666087
## 7     hospital_3     c     0.39663460
## 8     hospital_2     c     0.53064144
## 9     hospital_3     c     0.76015632
## 10    hospital_3     c     0.76801890
```

Without `group_by()` you just get the mortality rates from least to greatest:

```
df %>%
  arrange(mortality_rate)

## Source: local data frame [10 x 3]
## 
##    hospital_name state mortality_rate
## 1     hospital_3     c     0.02487033
## 2     hospital_1     c     0.09937557
## 3     hospital_1     b     0.15293591
## 4     hospital_1     c     0.35666087
## 5     hospital_1     b     0.37417167
## 6     hospital_3     c     0.39663460
## 7     hospital_2     c     0.53064144
## 8     hospital_1     b     0.54561856
## 9     hospital_3     c     0.76015632
## 10    hospital_3     c     0.76801890
```

Comment: Here also the answer is similar to @jalapic.  I don't know whether the group_by is needed here `arrange(df, State, Hospital.Name, Mortality.Rate)`

Comment: Yes, the `group_by` is needed to sort within states, rather than within the data frame as a whole. See `?dplyr::group_by`.

Comment: Can you show some examples where this will differ. I tried your example with a `set.seed(24)`.  Got the same output with or without groupby

Comment: Edited the answer as you suggest.

Comment: My code was `arrange(df, state, hospital_name, mortality_rate)`

Comment: Yes, that will also work for sorting. But using `group_by()` is a better match conceptually for what the question is asking, and permits further analysis, such as taking the top n within a grouping.

Comment: I thought using only `arrange` would be faster if the OP needs just to order

Answer (score 3):

If we already in loading needles (for this specific operation) packages, here's a package (`data.table`) that could be useful in a sense of sorting the data *by reference* (without copying it and the need of using `<-`) using the `setorder` or `setkey` functions

```
library(data.table)
setorder(setDT(df), State, Mortality.Rate, Hospital.Name)
```

Though, you could potentially mimic base R syntax and order the data while creating a copy (though with improved speed because `data.table` calls its `forder` under the hood)

```
setDT(df)[order(State, Mortality.Rate, Hospital.Name)]
```

Comment: how to order but imposing a group column as reference?

Answer (score 1):

This came to my mind

```
 df <- df[with(df, order(State, as.numeric(Mortality.Rate), Hospital.Name)]
```

Check out this post [How to sort a dataframe by column(s)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns-in-r)

Comment: Isn't this similar to @Jthorpe's answer

Comment: Like akrun said, also, where's the `Hospital.Name` part?

Answer (score 0):

### assign a variable "result". and also assuming you want to find the avg mortality for each state

```
result <- df %<%
                 arrange(Mortality.Rate) %<%
                 order_by(State) %<%
                 summarize(mean(Mortality.Rate)
view(result)
```