# How to sort a character column in data frame based on groups in R?

Tags: r

Many similar questions have been asked that relate to this problem (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28649701/how-to-order-a-column-by-group-in-r) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36356533/sort-data-in-r-data-frame-within-subgroups) for examples). But none specifically answer my question.

In my data frame I have a column comprised of characters and `NA`s. Im trying to sort this column into groups that are based on other columns in my data frame. For example, if my data looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)

dfTest <- tibble(
  var = c("x1", NA, NA, "x4", NA, "x4", NA, NA, "x2", NA, NA, "x1", NA, NA, "x2", NA, NA,
          "x4", NA, "x4", NA, NA, 'x5', NA, NA, 'x2', NA, NA, "x1", NA, "x2", NA, NA, 'x5', NA, NA),
  nam = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,
          1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5),
  itr = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
          2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
)
> dfTest
# A tibble: 36 × 3
   var     nam   itr
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 x1        1     1
 2 NA        1     1
 3 NA        1     1
 4 x4        2     1
 5 NA        2     1
 6 x4        2     1
 7 NA        2     1
 8 NA        2     1
 9 x2        3     1
10 NA        3     1
11 NA        3     1
12 x1        4     1
13 NA        4     1
14 NA        4     1
15 x2        5     1
16 NA        5     1
17 NA        5     1
18 x4        1     2
19 NA        1     2
20 x4        1     2
21 NA        1     2
22 NA        1     2
23 x5        2     2
24 NA        2     2
25 NA        2     2
26 x2        3     2
27 NA        3     2
28 NA        3     2
29 x1        4     2
30 NA        4     2
31 x2        4     2
32 NA        4     2
33 NA        4     2
34 x5        5     2
35 NA        5     2
36 NA        5     2
>
```

The first thing I am trying to do is sort the `var` column by the `itr` column. But I want to retain the grouping seen in the `nam` column. In other words, Im trying to sort by the group structures.

so, for example, my desired output would look like this:

```
> dfTest
A tibble: 36 × 3
   var     nam   itr
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 x1        1     1
 2 NA        1     1
 3 NA        1     1
 4 x1        4     1
 5 NA        4     1
 6 NA        4     1
 7 x2        3     1
 8 NA        3     1
 9 NA        3     1
10 x2        5     1
11 NA        5     1
12 NA        5     1
13 x4        2     1
14 NA        2     1
15 x4        2     1
16 NA        2     1
17 NA        2     1
18 x5        2     2
19 NA        2     2
20 NA        2     2
21 x5        5     2
22 NA        5     2
23 NA        5     2
24 x4        1     2
25 NA        1     2
26 x4        1     2
27 NA        1     2
28 NA        1     2
29 x1        4     2
30 NA        4     2
31 x2        4     2
32 NA        4     2
33 NA        4     2
34 x2        3     2
35 NA        3     2
36 NA        3     2
```

For clarification, in the above example, we can see that when `itr = 1` we have grouped the `var` column by the `nam` column in order of the frequency of the groups (i.e., when `itr = 1` the group containing `x1, NA, NA` appeared the most often, followed by the group containing `x2, NA, NA` etc).

Any suggestions as to how I could achieve this?

Comment: I will edit the question to make it more clear

Comment: If you ask a question and it gets answered as you asked it, but then you realize you asked the wrong question, don't edit the question to change it, instead ask a new question taking what you learned to make it clearer from the start.

Comment: I'll leave it up to you. If you'd like, I'll delete my answer so your question will show up as unanswered and maybe draw some attention, but at this point it's so long that I'm not sure someone else will answer. Concise questions get a lot more attention. If you still don't have an answer next time I'm free I can try to take a look at the edits, but that will probably tomorrow. My strong recommendation is roll back the edits and ask a new question.

Comment: I have rolled back to the original version and will ask a new question. Apologies for the confusion

Comment: Apologies on my end as well. Best thing to do might be to just delete this question at this point. Original version wasn't super clear, and I misunderstood it as well. Just provided an answer at the new question that I'm pretty confident in. (And the new version is getting upvotes and attention)