# How to sort a character column by frequency of groups in R?

Tags: r

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70700242/how-to-sort-a-character-column-in-data-frame-based-on-groups-in-r), but upon review, it wasn't very clear and was asking the wrong questions. Im asking another question now to try and make more clear my issue.

In my data frame I have a column comprised of characters and `NA`s. Im trying to sort this column into groups based on their frequency, whilst preserving the structure of the groups. For example, if my data looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)

dfTest <- 
structure(list(var = c("x1", NA, NA, "x4", NA, "x4", NA, NA, 
"x5", NA, NA, "x1", NA, NA, "x5", NA, NA, "x4", NA, "x4", NA, 
NA, "x5", NA, NA, "x2", NA, NA, "x1", NA, "x2", NA, NA, "x5", 
NA, NA), nam = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 
5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5
), itr = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -36L))

> dfTest
# A tibble: 36 × 3
   var     nam   itr
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 x1        1     1
 2 NA        1     1
 3 NA        1     1
 4 x4        2     1
 5 NA        2     1
 6 x4        2     1
 7 NA        2     1
 8 NA        2     1
 9 x5        3     1
10 NA        3     1
11 NA        3     1
12 x1        4     1
13 NA        4     1
14 NA        4     1
15 x5        5     1
16 NA        5     1
17 NA        5     1
18 x4        1     2
19 NA        1     2
20 x4        1     2
21 NA        1     2
22 NA        1     2
23 x5        2     2
24 NA        2     2
25 NA        2     2
26 x2        3     2
27 NA        3     2
28 NA        3     2
29 x1        4     2
30 NA        4     2
31 x2        4     2
32 NA        4     2
33 NA        4     2
34 x5        5     2
35 NA        5     2
36 NA        5     2
```

What I am trying to do is sort the `var` column by frequency for each `itr`, whilst preserving the the grouping seen in the `nam` column. So, for example, when `itr = 1`, and when we group `var` and `nam`, we can see that the structure `x1, NA, NA` appears twice, as does the structure `x5, NA, NA`. When `itr = 2` the group `x5, NA, NA` appears twice, and all the rest of the groups appear only once.

My desired output would look something like the data frame below. Where, we can see that each `var` structure, has been sorted according to their frequency for each `itr`.

```
# A tibble: 36 × 3
   var     nam   itr
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 x1        1     1
 2 NA        1     1
 3 NA        1     1
 4 x1        4     1
 5 NA        4     1
 6 NA        4     1
 7 x5        3     1
 8 NA        3     1
 9 NA        3     1
10 x5        5     1
11 NA        5     1
12 NA        5     1
13 x4        2     1
14 NA        2     1
15 x4        2     1
16 NA        2     1
17 NA        2     1
18 x5        2     2
19 NA        2     2
20 NA        2     2
21 x5        5     2
22 NA        5     2
23 NA        5     2
24 x4        1     2
25 NA        1     2
26 x4        1     2
27 NA        1     2
28 NA        1     2
29 x2        3     2
30 NA        3     2
31 NA        3     2
32 x1        4     2
33 NA        4     2
34 x2        4     2
35 NA        4     2
36 NA        4     2
```

I hope that makes sense.

Any suggestions as to how I could achieve this type of sorting whilst preserving the structure of each `var` by `nam`?

Comment: I was advised by another experienced user to rollback my edits from my previous question and ask a new separate question.

Comment: Hmm, I see that now. I guess I will leave it up to you. Another way around the "no one looks at old questions" problem is to start a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties). That should easily get you an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but note that `var` can be grouped according to `cumsum(!is.na(var))`.

Comment: @MikaelJagan that's not quite right, the `var` groups are already well marked by the `nam` column, and some of them do have multiple non-NA values, e.g., rows 4-8 are one "structure", and have values `x4, NA, x4, NA, NA`

Comment: @GregorThomas I see - my mistake, then. My understanding was that rows 4-8 contained 2 segments, not 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I think this works. I've left in my helper columns for transparency, but you can remove them from the final select.

Basically, we collapse the data to one row per `itr:nam` group, keeping `var` around **both** as a concatenated string that we can group on and as a `list` column we can `unnest` to restore the original structures. We then count the frequency for each `var_string`, and sort the rows by this frequency, using the minimum `nam` value within the `var_string` group as a tiebreaker. This is the bulk of the work. We then unnest the data to get back to the original structure in the now-sorted order.

```
dfTest %>% 
  group_by(itr, nam) %>%
  summarize(var_string = paste(var, collapse = ";"), var= list(var))  %>%
  group_by(itr, var_string) %>%
  add_tally %>%
  mutate(min_nam = min(nam)) %>%
  arrange(itr, desc(n), min_nam, nam) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  unnest(var) %>%
  select(var, nam, itr, everything()) %>%
  print.data.frame
#     var nam itr     var_string n min_nam
# 1    x1   1   1       x1;NA;NA 2       1
# 2  <NA>   1   1       x1;NA;NA 2       1
# 3  <NA>   1   1       x1;NA;NA 2       1
# 4    x1   4   1       x1;NA;NA 2       1
# 5  <NA>   4   1       x1;NA;NA 2       1
# 6  <NA>   4   1       x1;NA;NA 2       1
# 7    x5   3   1       x5;NA;NA 2       3
# 8  <NA>   3   1       x5;NA;NA 2       3
# 9  <NA>   3   1       x5;NA;NA 2       3
# 10   x5   5   1       x5;NA;NA 2       3
# 11 <NA>   5   1       x5;NA;NA 2       3
# 12 <NA>   5   1       x5;NA;NA 2       3
# 13   x4   2   1 x4;NA;x4;NA;NA 1       2
# 14 <NA>   2   1 x4;NA;x4;NA;NA 1       2
# 15   x4   2   1 x4;NA;x4;NA;NA 1       2
# 16 <NA>   2   1 x4;NA;x4;NA;NA 1       2
# 17 <NA>   2   1 x4;NA;x4;NA;NA 1       2
# 18   x5   2   2       x5;NA;NA 2       2
# 19 <NA>   2   2       x5;NA;NA 2       2
# 20 <NA>   2   2       x5;NA;NA 2       2
# 21   x5   5   2       x5;NA;NA 2       2
# 22 <NA>   5   2       x5;NA;NA 2       2
# 23 <NA>   5   2       x5;NA;NA 2       2
# 24   x4   1   2 x4;NA;x4;NA;NA 1       1
# 25 <NA>   1   2 x4;NA;x4;NA;NA 1       1
# 26   x4   1   2 x4;NA;x4;NA;NA 1       1
# 27 <NA>   1   2 x4;NA;x4;NA;NA 1       1
# 28 <NA>   1   2 x4;NA;x4;NA;NA 1       1
# 29   x2   3   2       x2;NA;NA 1       3
# 30 <NA>   3   2       x2;NA;NA 1       3
# 31 <NA>   3   2       x2;NA;NA 1       3
# 32   x1   4   2 x1;NA;x2;NA;NA 1       4
# 33 <NA>   4   2 x1;NA;x2;NA;NA 1       4
# 34   x2   4   2 x1;NA;x2;NA;NA 1       4
# 35 <NA>   4   2 x1;NA;x2;NA;NA 1       4
# 36 <NA>   4   2 x1;NA;x2;NA;NA 1       4
```

Comment: That's what you said last time ;) ... but this time I think you're right.